# Rails Unknown attribute error, but attribute does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, polymorphic-associations

I'm getting the error unknown attribute id when I run

```
@user.payments.create(payment_params)
```

I know this means I need a user_id in my payments table. But I'm using polymorphic associations (perhaps incorrectly?) and my payments table has a payee_id and a payer_id (for each "type" of user). In the above method the @user instance is a payer.

Here are the payment and user models:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'payee_id'
  belongs_to :payer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'payer_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
end
```

And the create action in the payment controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_or_create_by(user_params)
  @payment = @user.payments.create(payment_params)
end
```

The polymorphic associations are confusing me. How can I correct this error?

Comment: Rails is looking for a attribute `user_id` in the payments table. Not positive, but you may have to specify the `:foreign_key` on the user's `has_many` relationship as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a polymorphic association. You have to define relations correctly to get the payments you need to get. From the code i understand that this is kind of loan application.

The user in the above model does not have a single type of payment. There are two types of payments, the ones user gets money for, lets say `incoming_payments` and the one which user has to give money `outgoing_payments`. The relation should be defined like

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'payee_id'
  belongs_to :payer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'payer_id'
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :incoming_payments, :class_name => 'Payment', :foreign_key => 'payee_id'
  has_many :outgoing_payments, :class_name => 'Payment', :foreign_key => 'payer_id'
end
```

So if the user you are querying payments for is a payer then you should call `user.outgoing_payements` and if the user is a lender then you should call `user.incoming_payments`

Comment: I did as you said, which makes sense to me. But now when I call user.outgoing_payments I get a NameError: uninitialized constant User::Payments

What's weirder is that outgoing_payments is listed as an instance method of user when I run user.methods

Comment: I take that back. outgoing_payments is not listed as a method of an instance of User.

Comment: The class_name should be 'Payment', type... edited the answer